# Predicting with SMOTE

Tags: python, pandas, tree, prediction, smote

If I have a training dataset that has 1083 samples and a testing dataset that has 79871 samples, how do I go about making the samples equal? I have been using SMOTE but now I get the error

`ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'`

My code:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn import utils


over_sampler = SMOTE()

print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(x))
print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(ans))

x_over,y_over = over_sampler.fit_resample(x,ans)
y_over = pd.Series(y_over)
y_over
```

x, ans are the continuous-multioutput

Comment: Seems the output is continuous number. You would need Regression method than Classification to predict continuous value. Another way, Classification can be done by categorizing the output, for example divide ranges of the output value into Low, Medium, High. Then use the resampling on that.

Comment: The output should be either 1 or 2, I dont know why it thinks it is continous

Comment: You can change the value as text, 'one', 'two' or naming a label like 'true', 'false',

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure you can use RandomUnderSampler to downsampling the majority class to be equal with the minority, and SMOTE oversampler to upsampling the minority to be equal with the majority class.

can you explain more about predict certain number of predictions?

Comment: I thought you could ask predict to predict 79871 samples for example